# Adjoin custom form region to the task-details page in outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I want to adjoin a custom form region to the task inspectors details page. It works fine adding the region to the basic task page. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/associating-a-form-region-with-an-outlook-message-class?view=vs-2019#understand-outlook-message-classes) list contains the outlook message class for taks but there is no information about the respective available pages in addition to the default page.

So is it possilbe to adjoin a custom region on specific pages only?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an [Outlook form region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/creating-outlook-form-regions?view=vs-2019). And you can prevent them from displaying dynamically at runtime, see [How to: Prevent Outlook from displaying a form region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-prevent-outlook-from-displaying-a-form-region?view=vs-2019) for more information.

Comment: I already created a form region and I managed to add it to the task page in the task inspector. But instead I want to add it to the details page in the task inspector.